# What is so detailed in kitchen-sink?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context, word-choice, usage

Why do we use "kitchen-sink" to tell that something is made of a great detail, at the best quality etc.? Here is a part from [Wikipedia article on Microsoft Flight Simulator 2020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Flight_Simulator_%282020_video_game%29?wprov=sfla1) (emphasis mine):

> As a comprehensive simulator that steadily guides players to aviation from square zero, **combined with kitchen-sink graphics**, The Guardian concluded that Flight Simulator "captures the wonder of flight, and the spiritual and emotional rush of seeing the world in a different way."

Kitchen-sink seems to be a fairly simply, usually not rich in details and usually not of the best quality device or object.

Comment: The *[everything but the] **kitchen sink*** metaphoric usage isn't really to do with "great detail, best quality". The cited example usage is quirky, to say the least, but it just means the graphics capabilities include [emphatically] ***everything***. You might never encounter adjectival "kitchen-sink" used like this again, and my advice is *don't copy it*.

Comment: The fixed phrase is an exaggeration, saying that something is "loaded", i.e, contains many features, including optional extra ones, One would say _It has everything but the kitchen sink_ (meaning that the sink, being large, heavy, and fixed in place, had to be left out -- but that was the **only** thing left out). It's typically American overreaching. We do go in for tall tales here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an phrase "everything but the kitchen sink". It means "[everything imaginable](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/9/messages/469.html)".  It seems to have originated in soldier slang.  "We threw everything but the kitchen sink at the enemy".  The kitchen sink would be heavy and hard to move and not very effective as a weapon.

It came to mean "with every imaginable feature".  (phrases.org.uk has "[he bought a new car that] had everything but the kitchen sink."  That would be a very luxury car. It has everything that you could want in a car.)

The expression is now a cliché.

Here this expression is being adapted. By saying "kitchin sink graphics" they mean
the graphics has everything that you could want in the graphics. (ie high detail, fast, complex).  I understand the reference and meaning, but I've never heard "kitchen sink" being used like this before.

Comment: "_but I've never heard "kitchen sink" being used like this before_" -- same here, thank you. The expressions that you gave as an examples ("_We threw everything but the kitchen sink at the enemy_" and "_He bought a new car that had everything but the kitchen sink_") are obvious and pretty much self-explanatory even to me (non-native English speaker). But the one cited in question is quite very confusing. Thank you for explanation.